# how to disable timer from start again after click refresh button?

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I want to ask. How to disable timer from start again after click refresh button? This is my code :

```
session_start();
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE testNum='$testnum'");
$rec2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

<script language="JavaScript">
var hoursleft = <?php echo $rec2['testDurationHour'];?>;
var minutesleft = <?php echo $rec2['testDurationMin'];?>; 
var secondsleft = 0;

end = new Date();
end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes()+minutesleft);
end.setSeconds(end.getSeconds()+secondsleft);

function cd(){
now = new Date();
diff = end - now;
diff = new Date(diff);
var sec = diff.getSeconds();
var min = diff.getMinutes();
var hr = diff.getHours()-1;

if (min < 10){ 
min = "0" + min;
}
if (sec < 10){
sec = "0" + sec;
}
if(now >= end){
window.alert("Time is up. Press OK to continue."); 
document.forms[0].submit();
}
else
{
document.getElementById("cdtime").innerHTML =  min + ":" + sec;
setTimeout("cd()", 10); 
}
}
window.onload = cd;
```

how can I disable timer from starting again after user click refresh button?

Answer (score 0):

**I know it's a quick and dirty answer. But I think it's sufficient.**

You can use session to check the test number is being taken, so whenever the test page has been refreshed for the same test number, hours and minutes left is set to 0 (it will prevent your time restarting again) and if not (your test page is not being refreshed) you can fill it by the necessary value from your database. Note: I use "added" for additional code and "modified" when I wrote some modifications to your code. See below.

```
session_start();

// added
$hoursLeft = 0;
$minutesLeft = 0;

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE testNum='$testnum'");
$rec2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

// added
if(!isset($_SESSION['testnum']) || $_SESSION['testnum'] <> $testnum) { 
    $_SESSION['testnum'] = $testnum;
    $hoursLeft = $rec2['testDurationHour'];
    $minutesLeft = $rec2['testDurationMin'];
} else {
    $msg = "It seems you've been refreshing your page and it's prohibited. Press OK to continue";
}

<script language="JavaScript">
// modified
var hoursleft = <?php echo $hoursLeft ?>;

// modified
var minutesleft = <?php echo $minutesLeft ?>; 
var secondsleft = 0;

end = new Date();
end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes()+minutesleft);
end.setSeconds(end.getSeconds()+secondsleft);

function cd(){
    now = new Date();
    diff = end - now;
    diff = new Date(diff);
    var sec = diff.getSeconds();
    var min = diff.getMinutes();
    var hr = diff.getHours()-1;

    if (min < 10) { 
        min = "0" + min;
    }
    if (sec < 10) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }
    if(now >= end) {
        // modified
        var msg = <?php if (isset($msg)) echo '"'.$msg.'"'; else echo '"'."Time is up. Press OK to continue.".'"'; ?>;
        window.alert(msg); 
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("cdtime").innerHTML =  min + ":" + sec;
        setTimeout("cd()", 10); 
    }
}
window.onload = cd;
```